# proof or disproof adding two minimal values to a B tree and then delete them

Tags: database, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree, b-tree

I came across a question and I'm not sure about the right answer:

> We insert two new minimal values *w* and *z*, with *w > z*, in a B tree --
> first we insert *w* and then *x*. Right afterwards we delete them by the same order. Does the original B tree struct stay the same, or do we get a different order in the tree?

Answer (score 0):

It is not guaranteed that the B-tree remains the same. It would be guaranteed if the deletions happened in the opposite order as the insertions, but if the order is:

- Insert *w*
- Insert *z*
- Delete *w*
- Delete *z*

...then it depends on implementation choices, notably how the deletion of a value that occurs in a non-leaf node is dealt with.

Here is a counter example [2-3 tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%E2%80%933_tree), i.e. a B-tree of order 3:

```
       [5  ,  -]   
      /    |
   [4,-] [6,7]
```

So we have a root with (separator) value 5 and an empty slot. There are two leaves: the first leaf is filled half, with value 4, while the right leaf is completely occupied with values 6 and 7.

Now let *w*=2 and *z*=1.

After we insert 2, we get this tree -- nothing special happens:

```
       [5  ,  -]   
      /    |
   [2,4] [6,7]
```

Then, to insert 1, we must split the left most leaf, and move 2 as separator value to the parent node:

```
       [2  ,  5]   
      /    |    \
   [1,-] [4,-] [6,7]
```

Now we get to the critical part: the deletion of 2 gives us a choice. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree#Deletion_from_an_internal_node) describes that choice as follows:

> Choose a new separator (**either** the largest element in the left subtree **or** the smallest element in the right subtree), remove it from the leaf node it is in, and replace the element to be deleted with the new separator.

If we choose the *second* option, then that means we choose 4 as new separator value to replace the value 2. This gives us the following intermediate situation:

```
       [4  ,  5]   
      /    |    \
   [1,-] [-,-] [6,7]
```

The empty leaf in the middle is underflowing, so we try to rotate. We must perform a rotation with the right-sided neighbor, as the other one does not have enough values, and so we move the 6 up, and the 5 down:

```
       [4  ,  6]   
      /    |    \
   [1,-] [5,-] [7,-]
```

...and the tree is valid again. But,... it is not the original tree.

So, this one counter example is enough proof that the predicate is false.

If however there would be the extra information that the algorithm always takes the *first* alternative for the deletion of an internal value, then the predicate seems to be true.

Comment: Could you leave some feedback on this answer?